# Big-query does now cast automatically long decimal values to numeric, when running a load job from UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a value "1.8299324324324324" which if I insert using DML statement to BigQuery, it rounds it off and inserts in Bigquery.

However, for the same value, if BigQuery load job using csv file on console, I get below error.

> "location" : "query",
>         "message" : "Invalid NUMERIC value: 1.8299324324324324 Field: test; Value: 1.8299324324324324",
>         "reason" : "invalidQuery"

Just wanted to check if this is a limitation of Bigquery, that in load job it is not able to cast or understand this value and how to solve it?

Answer (score 16):

According to the [documentation, BigQuery's `NUMERIC` type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type) has a limit of 9 decimal digits:

> Decimal values with 38 decimal digits of precision and 9 decimal digits of scale.

As an alternative, using the (less precise) `FLOAT64` type should bypass this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I performed some tests and I could replicate the behavior that you are mentioning; however, I couldn't find any documentation indicating that it's a BigQuery limitation. Given that a different behavior is observed in both (using DML statements and load jobs), it looks like an issue with the platform and I've filed an issue in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/135053344). I recommend you follow up on this matter there.

The workarounds that I can suggest you is to create a new table and define the field as [float](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#floating-point-type) instead of numeric or truncate the numbers content into the CSV file before uploading it to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and got some bizarre behaviour when attempting to round/truncate float precision in Python. The BigQuery load job would add false precision, pushing the value beyond the 9 decimal limit regardless of rounding/truncation. So for example, I would truncate the value 53.681482688356219 to 53.681482688 using

```
n = 53.681482688356219
trunc = float(f"{n:.9f}")
```

but BigQuery would interpret this as 53.681482690000003. Failing with:

> 'Invalid NUMERIC value: 53.681482690000003'

As a workaround, I casted my Python float value to a string before insertion. The BigQuery [load_table_from_dataframe](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_dataframe) function takes care of the conversion from string to NUMERIC as long as you have manually specified the schema in the job_config.

```
schema = bqclient.schema_from_json('bigquery_schemas/'+path+'.json')

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=False,
    schema=schema,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
)
```

Comment: Casting to string still doesn't work for me. BigQuery tells me: "Could not convert value to string" for a value such as `20263.3349609375`

Comment: @zakdances try truncating to 9 decimals (you've got 10 there in your example, which is above the BQ limit). Alternatively, if you are able to use the FLOAT64 type instead of NUMERIC, that could solve your problem.